# How to buy (and activate!) a Mac/iOS Developer Program without paying VAT?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos

I had this problem myself so I figured out I'll explain…

As a European (not living in Ireland) you'd have to pay/loose 14€ of Irish VAT when buying your Dev Program. So the solution is to call Apple (their "Business" people), give them your VAT Number, then they can "buy" you (by giving your credit card number over the phone) the Dev Program for approx. 65 € (so the price without VAT).

You then get an Invoice and an "activation code". This is where the weirdness begins :-)

They ask you to click this link, but it's misleading. It won't "activate"/"renew" your Dev Program. Instead, here what you need to do. (Check the answer)

Comment: Put the solution in the solution part. I'd love to mark it as a good answer, but all is in the question.

Comment: sorry folks, now the answer is the answers ;-)

Comment: well, your post is inside my favourites, since it's useful :) a bit different from the kind that we're used to (question-answer), but still it's a nice contribution! thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused about the benefit of this. What is the VAT rate where you live? If you're registered for VAT (have a VAT number) then you can just claim the VAT back.

Comment: You can't, at least in Germany. And where you can, it's mostly pretty cumbersome, so if you have the option to not pay it in the first place, you'd better do it. Since it's a product I use in Germany, I'm allowed to do so. If I buy something which I "use" (like a conference) in another country though, I might not be able to "not pay" the VAT, in which case you'll have to go the other way around (reclaiming it).

Comment: Generally, you can't reclaim VAT paid to a different EU country from your local tax authority. Instead you have to reclaim those taxes from the originating country. There is a central EU-wide process for that but still, there are different minimum thresholds (like 50 € reclaimable VAT) from country to country. So better not pay the VAT at the first place! Unfortunately, Apple makes purchases with VAT ID very difficult (iTunes still doesn't support it), so this is valuable!

Comment: Question is about taxes, not programming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Do as if you'd "buy" a Mac Dev Program (so the full fledge 80 €), until you have this in your "Cart" but don't Checkout. DO NOT. You have already paid, ¡¿are you loco?! :-)
2. Now find back this "activation" email, click this link, copy paste the code in the box, and click the button, and boom!

Your program is now activated/renewed, you get an E-mail confirming your purchase, and your cart is now empty!

You're welcome! ;-)